# Missing characters when printing in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pdf, printing, cups

I have a pdf that I was printing recently, and on the final printout there is a single character that doesn't print.  It is the greek letter phi, and the pdf was built with pdflatex.  The phi shows up in every pdf reader I have tried, and if I convert to a ps using `pdftops` before printing that solves the problem.  Also, I sent the pdf to a buddy who has a very similar machine (Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, with the same printer drivers), and he was able to print it (to the same printer) and the character showed up.

Clearly I have a workaround, but I'm more curious as to where I should be looking to figure out what is causing this bug?  What is the printing "toolchain", and where could it be going wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you're missing some font library/libraries on your local machine

Comment: Agreed.  What's the name of the font you wrote the character in?  If you know that, you can find the package to install.

Comment: I'll look into that... but why does it show up in the pdf readers, and how can `pdftops` convert correctly if I am missing fonts?

Comment: So to figure out what font that specific character was I recompiled the pdf using the same pdflatex preamble, but only left the single character in the document.  The only font listed also shows up in the original pdf, thus I conclude that it is indeed the correct one.  Anyway, it is listed as "StandardSymL-Slant_167" it is a Type 1 embedded subset font.

Comment: The fact that `pdftops` converts your document correctly is not strange at all since you can view the document in your pdf readers. Does this happen to every pdf document that has the *phi* character or is it only for this document? If it's just for this document, then maybe there's something wrong with the document itself. If not, then my guess is that *gnome print* cannot access the font library for some reason (permissions maybe?). That would be rather strange though but then again, I've never heard of this problem before.

Comment: Well, if I include a particular package in the latex preamble, the _phi_ does not print, but also the font changes to a different font (which prints fine).  Interestingly, if I use latex to compile the tex file to a dvi instead of a pdf, it prints no problem even with the "bad" version of _phi_.

Comment: Having a similar issue, I found printing the PDF with `lpr` was another workaround.